# ¿Por qué al agregarle el margin-top a mi elemento no funciona?

Tags: css

Estoy aprendiendo flotantes y estoy replicando layouts que voy encontrando de páginas web por ahí, y me topé con el problema de al querer dar un espaciado entre un elemento flotante y otro normal, no me lo arroja.

Quiero agregar una declaración **margin-top: 80px;** en mi página web.
Estos son mis códigos.

```css
body{
    background: rgba(250,250,200,255);
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
}

body > header > nav > img, ul, p{
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

nav > ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul, p{
    margin-top: 3.125em;
}

body > main > section{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 80000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo3.css">
    <title>Salud Digna LAYOUT</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <img src="saluddignalogo.png" alt="logo de salud digna navideño">
            <ul>
                <li>COVID-19</li>
                <li>Conócenos</li>
                <li>Servicios</li>
                <li>Pacientes</li>
                <li>Atención a empresas</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Ubica tu clínica</p>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section>
            CONTENIDO
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: captura de pantalla del layout]

Quisiera que haya una separación entre "CONTENIDO" y todo el cuadro de arriba. El de arriba es flotante y el de abajo no. **Quiero hacerlo sin usar flexbox, grid, id's, clases o demás.**

Comment: mira, te dejo una pregunta muy similar a la tuya. [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198269/margin-top-not-working-with-clear-both#)

Comment: gracias Luis por comentar